# Visual Studio - One click publish files outside of the website root

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm trying to publish files that are unrelated to the solution as part of a one-click publish job.

This would be relatively standard, similar to what is outlined [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files) and [here too](http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx).

However, the files themselves need to reside one folder above the actual root of the website.

If I try to specify a relative path outside of the website directory, such as `<DestinationRelativePath>..\Data\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>` this just results in the publish skipping the item, since it claims it is up to date (in reality there isn't anything there so it can't be up to date).

I've had a quick look and can't find a way to specify an absolute path, is this something that would be possible, or is there a better approach to take here?

Answer (score 0):

As part of the properties of the file you want to copy you can set it to be "Copy Always" this could resolve the issue if it is just a date issue.